# Why the view's data context is the view model while using Data Template?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

so my question is: How can the view link to the view model if we use Data Template?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:PersonViewModel}">
  <my:PersonView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Because, I thought that the Data Template is just to define the visual structure of a data object (in this case is a view model). So how can the view know its viewmodel is an item in the list ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The DataType property is used as a key to automatically select a DataTemplate that matches the type of the `Content` object of a ContentControl or ContentPresenter.

Since a ContentControl or ContentPresenter is used as "item container" for the items in an ItemsControl, it would also automatically select a matching DataTemplate.

However, you won't typically utilize automatic DataTemplate selection in an ItemsControl, but instead directly set the ItemTemplate property:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:PersonView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

The value of the DataContext property of the elements inside the DataTemplate is then provided by [property value inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) from the ContentControl or ContentPresenter.